# I am trying to create a folium map with markers and I keep getting TypeError: must be real number, not str

Tags: python, folium

```
data = pd.read_csv("organization.csv", names=['organization_name', 'latitude', 'longitude'])
m = folium.Map(location=[20,0], tiles='Mapbox Bright', zoom_start=2) 
for i in range(len(data)):
   folium.Marker([data.iloc[i]['longitude'], data.iloc[i]['latitude']], popup=data.iloc[i]['organization_name']).add_to(m)
```

How do I fix this error?

```
data = pd.read_csv("organization.csv", names=['organization_name', 'latitude', 'longitude']) 
m = folium.Map(location=[20,0], tiles='Mapbox Bright', zoom_start=2) 
for i in range(len(data)): 
    long = float(data.iloc[i]['longitude']) 
    lat = float(data.iloc[i]['latitude']) 
    popup = folium.Popup(data.iloc[i]['organization_name'], parse_html=True) 
    folium.Marker([lat, long], str(popup)).add_to(m)
```

The output is just a blank white box, no error message.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting this error?

Comment: the 4th line: folium.Marker([long, lat], popup=data.iloc[i]['organization_name']).add_to(m)

Comment: What Paul just said.  Not related to your error, coordinates must be passed [lat,long] not [long, lat]

Comment: Also, In addition to the full traceback, could you please post the output of `data.dtypes`

Comment: I tried fixing my code and this is what I came up with, the output is a blank white box, no error message. Don't know what the problem is. Thanks 
         `data = pd.read_csv("organization.csv", names=['organization_name', 'latitude', 'longitude'])
m = folium.Map(location=[20,0], tiles='Mapbox Bright', zoom_start=2)
for i in range(len(data)):
    long = float(data.iloc[i]['longitude'])
    lat = float(data.iloc[i]['latitude'])
    popup = folium.Popup(data.iloc[i]['organization_name'], parse_html=True)
    folium.Marker([lat, long], str(popup)).add_to(m)
m` @PaulRooney @BobHaffner

Comment: I have updated the question @PaulRooney

Comment: @Nikki the important thing to include is the traceback. You should consider creating an [m.c.v.e](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This makes it really easy for another developer to see your issue and recommend a fix. If we are left guessing as to what your input is. It's very difficult to know much about it. It would be simple to create just add some small representative input file. I think the code is already self contained and runnable, just needs import statements (easy for us to add ourselves).

Comment: Nikki, looks like you got past the error.  I'm guessing the conversion of lat and long to a float did the trick.  Regarding your blank map, I usually see this in one of two cases.   1) You're using a Jupyter notebook and have more than a couple thousand points to plot  2) The popup text (organization)  contains a character (eg apostrophe) that html doesn't like.  You can get around 1 by saving the map and opening it in your preferred browser.

Comment: If 2 is your problem you can remove the offending characters or escape them eg `popup = folium.Popup(html.escape(data.iloc[i]['organization_name']), parse_html=True)`  Note: html is part of the std lib in python3